# Getting error while pass data fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, interface, fragment

Here I am getting value in String but when I set value in text view getting an error: null point exception.

```
  @Override
public void onDataPassed(String goodsName) {

    if (goodsName!=null){
        Log.d("@@goodsName",goodsName);

        tvgoodType.setText(goodsName);
    }

}
```

and I have Implemented like this  `GoodsType.OnDataPassedListener`

and from the activity I am passing like this

```
   @Override
public GoodsList goodsList(GoodsList goodsList) {
    goodsListTop = goodsList;

    goodsName   = goodsList.getGoodsName();
    Log.e("@@googdname", goodsName);
    return goodsListTop;

}
```

and I have initialized text view also

Comment: if you talking about error i suggest, you should post your stack trace as well

Comment: use shared viewmodel and livedata and you need not have interface as a callback.

Comment: please check if you have created reference for this view "tvgoodType" (using findViewById)